# Favorites tab on user page is populated with StackOverflow users

Tags: support, user-interface, stackexchange

I noticed that the [favorite users](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=favorite) tab on the main user page is filled with people from StackOverflow, rather than MathOverflow. It is also the same on the [math.SE favorite users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=favorite) tab.

Is this the first step of the programmer's plan to take over the world? I guess, first, they become the favorite popular clique on all stackexchange sites, and then....?

Or perhaps this is a Winter Bash thing?

[image: Favorite users]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Hmmnnnn.. It definitely reproduces for me. I am using Chrome on Windows. But the weird thing is that I just tried IE, and then I don't see that tab at all. In fact, I don't even know what a "favorite user" is...

Comment: I noticed now also a further error: on that favorite users tab, when I mouse hover over a user, a different user's information comes up.

Comment: Interesting. What is the favorite user tab even? I just followed the link, but how does one arrove there normally.

Comment: For me, it appears as one of the tabs on the user page. But only in Chrome, and not in IE.

Comment: But it is very odd, since it is like the page loads normally, and then is quickly changed to add that tab.

Comment: Strange. I do not see this in Chrome either (neither the tab nor is there anything odd when I follow your link); same in Firefox and IE.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe they show this just to you so that you also have some competition point-wise. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I feel like a mere inaccessible cardinal to their superstrongness and almost hugeness...

Comment: It seems that you have one tab more than I (and quid) do. Your link leads me to the reputation tab as if there was no favorite tab at all. Have you always had that tab, or is it a recent superpower?

Comment: I'm not sure; I just happened to notice it and click on it today. I seem to have it on all the SE sites, and it seems to work sensibly on the StackOverflow site.

Comment: I don't see this tab!

Comment: I looked at the source, and this favorites tab does not appear in the same <div> with the others; the only place the word "favorite" appears in the html source is in the line:  <meta property="og:url" content="http://meta.mathoverflow.net/users?tab=favorite"/>
.

Comment: I retagged [meta-tag:support] to save some moderator the effort of adding a status-tag for the bug-tag.

Answer (score 8):

I've realized that at some point I must have enabled the [FriendsStack](https://github.com/hsz/FriendsStack) extension in Chrome, and then completely forgotten about it. This extension supposedly allows one to favorite users, but I never ended up using it, and it now appears to presume that one is using StackOverflow rather than another stackexchange site. (Perhaps I could have made a different setting somehow and get it to work?)

I've now disabled this extension---the tab is now gone---and I apologize for the distraction.